# how to manage x overflow in real server

Tags: css, server, overflow

I turned overflow-x to hidden, everything works fine on my local server but when I take the code to a real server, the x overflow effect does not work...how is this possible? help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have to inspect the code after deploying it, click the pic of that element with css on inspect page and paste here so we can se what exactly the problem is . or give me the link of website and i will check

Comment: this is the link, kindly check and give me your feedback...thank you in advance
https://apps.demo.masyopnet.com/new

Answer (score -1):

> buddy overflow-x is already hidden when in the link u provided and i opened it in brave browser and ms edge, you should try opening this link in other browsers this might be a css browser compatibility problem

[image]